# Algebraic Integers and Polynomial Roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Given that $k_1,...,k_n$ are algebraic integers and the complex number $c$ is a root of the polynomial $X^n+k_1X^{n-1}+..+k_n$ it is an exercise to prove that $c$ is also an algebraic integer. I know that, by definition, an algebraic integer is a complex number that is a root of some monic polynomial with integer coefficients. My question then is I don't quite get what is there exactly to be proved here. Am I missing something?

Edit: So, can I say for any polynomial $f$ with algebraic coefficients and root $c$, there is a polynomial $g$ with integer coefficients and with same root $c$. Then perhaps multiplying some polynomials with some roots will give a polynomial with integer coefficients? But I am not sure of the details~

Comment: Knowing that something is a root of a polynomial with algebraic integer coefficients does not instantly prove that it is a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: The definition of algebraic integer requires that the $k_i$ be (rational) integers.  So there,is something to prove.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have edited my post according to my new understanding~

Comment: In general you need to do more than multiply by a constant.  After all you want to get a *monic* polynomial.  The result you are after here is usually approached by field extensions rather than by direct polynomial construction.

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, but this looks related to me: [Can every polynomial with algebraic coeffitients be transformed into a polymonial with integer coefficients and at least some of the same roots?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430084/can-every-polynomial-with-algebraic-coeffitients-be-transformed-into-a-polymonia)

Comment: Indeed and that is all rather abstract hm..could you outline this 'field extension' approach in more details?